# Example Pager view on android's site not working

Tags: android, eclipse, android-viewpager, fragment

I am typing in this example on android for the slider pager

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

But I am getting an error on this line
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSliderPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

Error Message:
The contructor *** is undefined

Can some explain why items wrong?

Code below

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SignOnActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

private static final int NUM_PAGES = 1;

private ViewPager mPager;

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_on);

    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSliderPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem()-1);
    }
}



public class ScreenSliderPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSliderPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new ScreenSliderPageFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change :
mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSliderPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

to :
mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSliderPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

Answer (score 0):

Your calling FragmnetManager is probably from different verion of support library. And it mismatches with the constructor in ScreenSliderPagerAdapter. Check the imports and just import v4 support library fragment Manager. Or just add v4 support library and remove others.